# How to draw a specific arrow in a flow chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to draw these arrows with tikz?

i can only create 3 seperate arrows connecting to the lower block.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Seeing your attempt would be better.

Comment: Just draw 1 arrow and lines from the other 2 blocks. You don't need to draw the arrow itself 3 times. If it is part of a tree, it may be easier to draw it that way. Hard to know without seeing the code, though.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
       box/.style = {draw, minimum width=22mm, minimum height=11mm}
                        ]
\node (n11) [box]               {};
\node (n12) [box,right=of n11]  {};
\node (n13) [box,right=of n12]  {};
\node (n2)  [box,below=of n12]  {};
% 
\draw[-Latex]   (n12) -- (n2); % <-- arrow
\draw   (n11.south) -- ++ (0,-0.4) -| (n13);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
in the case of two boxes in the first row with use of library `calc`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm and 4mm,
       box/.style = {draw, minimum width=22mm, minimum height=11mm}
                        ]
\node (n11) [box]               {};
\node (n12) [box,right=of n11]  {};
\coordinate[below=of $(n11.south)!0.5!(n12.south)$] (n13); % <-- added
\node (n2)  [box,below=of n13]  {};
%
\draw[-Latex]   (n13) -- (n2); % <-- arrow
\draw   (n11.south) |- (n13) -| (n12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you obtain:

[image]

Comment: Thx! This solution worked for me. But how would you do it when there are 2 (instead of 3) boxes that  have to be connected to the box below.

Comment: @Rick1212, I added solution for two boxes. See, if it can help you!